# Pure virtual class (interface) and internal array allocation of objects that inherit it

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pure-virtual

I am not sure that what I had in mind is doable, here it is what I want to achieve:

1. I am working on a C++ library which will be used by other developers (clients).
2. Library should expose headers that contain only interface classes (pure virtual classes). Nothing else.
3. Developers will call functions from exposed headers to allocate objects (for eg. rigid body), and to free them.
4. I would like to have a function that will return classic array of objects (allocated with new[]), not linked list or using std::

Here is how it could look like:

```
// exposed header (this is what developer will see)

// interface class
class someInterface
{
public:
    virtual void function1(void) = 0;
};

// public API to initialize array of objects and release it
someInterface *NewSomeClassArray(unsigned int num);
void ReleaseSomeClassArray(someInterface**a);
```

And

```
// source compiled into static library (source not available to developer)

// internal object type that inherits interface class
class someClass : public someInterface
{
protected:
    unsigned int someVar; // some internal variable.
public:
    someClass()
    {
        someVar = 10;
    }
    ~someClass()
    {

    }
    void function1(void)
    {
        printf("someVar = %d", someVar);
    }
};


// definition of public API functions

// will allocate array of objects of someClass type and return pointer to first one
someInterface *NewSomeClassArray(unsigned int num)
{
    return new someClass[num];
}

// will release array of allocated objects and set it to point to NULL 
// (simplified of course, no dynamic_cast etc. just as illustration)
void ReleaseSomeClassArray(someInterface**a)
{
    delete[] ((someClass*)(*a));
    (*a) = NULL;
}
```

So when a developer will link library into his project, and include header, he would do something like:

```
someInterface *test = NewSomeClassArray(2);
test[0].function1();
test[1].function1();
ReleaseSomeClassArray(&test);
```

However this above produces run-time violation when accessing test[1] (tested on XCode, in iOS project).

It does sound logical to me since size of "someInterface" differs from "someClass" (someClass is larger), hence offset [1] may not point to right memory block.

I'm curious if there is a way to make this work so developers can simply iterate through array of objects like this?

What I've seen so far in many of similarly organized libraries, you never get array of objects like this, rather linked-list or just a single object pointer. Is it possible to do it?

P.S. After accepting answer from @sp2danny (which is absolutely correct), I'd like to add (in case anyone will ever need it) a possible workaround:

```
// funciton in public API
someInterface * GetSomeClassArrayMember(someInterface*a,unsigned int i);
```

And inside library:

```
someInterface * GetSomeClassArrayMember(someInterface*a,unsigned int i)
{
    return &((someClass*)a)[i];
}
```

This would then be used like:

```
someInterface *test = NewSomeClassArray(2);
GetSomeClassArrayMember(test,0)->function1();
GetSomeClassArrayMember(test,1)->function1();
ReleaseSomeClassArray(&test);
```

This way, I could accommodate my client's request without exposing in headers anything but interface classes.

Comment: With proper destructors you don't need a specific "release" function, just the the application `delete` the object.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but that's not the question?

Comment: Write something like [this](http://bannalia.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/fast-polymorphic-collections.html) Its very efficient compared to the classic (`std::vector` of smart pointers) alternative. In my personal implementation/profillings, I got a 8x performance gains.

Comment: @Manu343726 but that's not related to my question?

Comment: Also, avoid release functions, avoid manual memory management and do proper RAII. Also don't throw away the Standard Library. Is part of the language. Imagine programming in Java without the Java API. Is exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: @Sinisa _'but that's not the question?'_ Yeah, but your _question_ seems to be lead from some misconception, that simply doesn't apply  for a reasonable answer.

Comment: Also, you can skip the dynamic allocation if you return a constant vector (i.e. `const std::vector`) instead. Less use of pointers, less points of failure. In fact, in C++ you should, and can, avoid pointers as much as possible.

Comment: I have commented that because does exactly what you want (Safe management of a hierarchical design) in a efficient manner.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ why would this be misconception, game physics engines that I've used are all based on the approach not to expose anything that could give too much of reverse engineer - just interface classes.

Comment: @Manu343726 No I didn't want safe management. But how to provide headers that will not expose anything except what is absolutely needed - interface classes, but in the same time to provide to developers comfort of iterating through an array of objects (for which they have only interface class) using brackets.

Comment: Games are not a good example of design, specifically proper C++ design. The game world begun with C and nowadays there are many many practices inherited from C just cos inhertia of the industry

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my use of ** was absolutely correct. it deletes array of objects and sets it to NULL. so instead of you doing: 1) delete[] array; array = NULL; you can call 2) deleteArray(&array) upon which will be set to NULL).

Comment: No, in C++ naked pointers should be avoided allways, if possible. Use references, the standard library containers etc. Don't do C nor Java

Comment: @Sinisa _'my use of ** was absolutely correct'_ If you'e sure about this, what you're actually bothering about?

Comment: @Manu343726 Ok I can respect that opinion but there is a reason why I am asking for this, being my client's request. Hence... I am looking to accommodate them. So do you say that there is no solution?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please do read my question, has nothing to do with deleting objects. Thank you.

Comment: @Sinisa Why doesn't `ReleaseSomeClassrray` just get the pointer `*`?  Why the `**`?  If it's to set the pointer to NULL, why?  Why so much hand-holding?  Let the client set their own pointer to NULL.  Even so, using `**` loses information on what is behind the innermost `*`.  It's akin to the mistake of assuming that a 2 dimensional array can be casted to a `**` and vice-versa.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ** was not a two dimensional array in this case. It's a pointer to a memory that contains the address of allocated object. And you are correct, it was to delete and then set to NULL. However this is not the question.

Comment: @Sinisa - The client can iterate all they want.  The problem is that your class has no information (besides naked pointers) on what is really behind those `*`'s when it's time to issue a `delete` call.  So pick your poison -- either the client has to delete them explicitly, or change your design.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie deleting is not a problem. Iteration is. That's what the question is about: they asked me if they can just ask for array of eg. 1000 objects, and then go through them using [] instead of linked list. I am on my end not willing to provide them with full headers, just interface classes.

Comment: @Sinisa - So if iterating is a problem, then there is no way to provide `[]` just out of the box like that.  It is impossible to do that, plain and simple.  If you overloaded operator [] and somehow get it to recognize *how* to get to the next element (similar to an iterator) then maybe...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for constructive answer. If you can post it as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is not trivial; the client code wont know the 
size of the actual objects, and therefore can't treat them as an array.

a possible workaround, is to make sure all objects, including the base, 
are of the same size.

a better solution is to use containers, iterators, smartpointers etc

Comment: Thanks for acceptable answer. I tried to explain this to client but they were stubborn with "go research it a bit, it's simple" attitude, so I had to give it a try here.